# Laravel filtering parts of a resource route by declaring it twice

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my Laravel app I have a resource route where I want to control access to individual routes based on a filter. I do this by declaring the resource with only the "view" routes and then declaring it again with only the "edit/create" routes in a nested filtered group. The filter is a custom one that check the logged-in user's capabilities.

My routes looks like this:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function()
{
    $edit_routes = ['create', 'store', 'destroy', 'edit', 'update'];

    Route::resource('things', 'ThingsController', ['except' => $edit_routes]);

    // We'll filter the routes that involve editing resources
    Route::group(['before' => 'edit_resource'], function() use ($edit_routes) 
    {
        Route::resource('things', 'ThingsController', ['only' => $edit_routes]);
    });
}
```

Is this correct? It seems not to work, although no errors are thrown. When I visit a route in the nested filter (e.g. things/create) I just get a blank page.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this correct?

No

> Is there a better way of achieving this?

Yes. [Here is a great blog post by Phil Sturgeon that explains why you should just define each route manually.](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil)

If you really want to continue using the Resource Controller, you can apply the `edit_resource` inside the controller constructor like this:

```
Route::resource('things', 'ThingsController', ['before' => 'auth']);
```

Then in your resource controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('edit_resource', array('only' => ['create', 'store', 'destroy', 'edit', 'update']);
}
```

Comment: Although I have followed your answer by placing the `beforeFilter` method in the controller's construct but it seems to not be working (no errors, but the filter is ignored). Does the `on` key apply to the controller's methods? I thought it only applied to the REST method. e.g. `'on' => ['POST']`...

Comment: It is to the controller method.

Comment: You can read more about it here: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters

Comment: Ah, it seems it should be `'only' => ['create', 'update'...]` not `on`.